# Google Chrome displays boxes at the beginning of all words in unicode text

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, facebook

I have this issue with chrome on windows 7, and it seems to be happening only with unicode text within facebook.
Screenshot: [image: 1]

The boxes disappear when I increase the zoom level by one step. But they come back when I switch to 100% zoom. Is there any permanent solution for this?

---

**Chrome 100%:**
[image: 2]

**Firefox:**
[image: 3]

**Chrome 110%:**
[image: 4]

**Chrome 90%:**
[image: 5]

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I couldn't get the pic to load.

Comment: The only boxes I see are where the font can't display all the foreign characters. Can you do some more screen shots that show the differences better? (I.e. between Chrome and other browsers, or between 100% and other zoom levels.)

Comment: Thanks. This issue happens to disappear sometimes. But, then the boxes show up later.

Comment: @neo1987: Can you provide a link with the same problem that is publicly accessible?

Comment: @Jay: http://www.facebook.com/search.of.my.heart

Comment: @neo1987: That URL is not acessible. It leads to a "*Page Not Found*" page. Any other URLs with the same issue?

Comment: @Jay: http://www.facebook.com/HavingFunahh